# Bug in message sending program

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am just experimenting on a messaging program which runs on one computer only. Okay, here's the problem: If I login as an user and send a message to another user, even when I login to the message receiving user, no messages are not there(it say no messages). Please help me out. You are also welcome to give your own suggestions and ways to simplify the code.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import sys
import tkMessageBox
import csv


accounts = dict()
messages = []
messagerec = []
messagesen = []

csvpath = "C:/Users/user1/Desktop/abc.csv"
csvreader = csv.reader(open(csvpath))

for y, z in csvreader:
    accounts[y] = z

def GetUser():
    user = userid.get()
    return user

def GetPass():
    password = passid.get()
    return password

def SignUp():
    def signupgo():
        newuser = newuserid.get()
        newpass = newpassid.get()
        if newuser in accounts:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Username Taken", 'Sorry! The username you have requested has already been taken. Please try another username.' [2])
        else:
            accounts[newuser] = newpass
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Account Created", 'Congratulations! Your account has been created' [2])
    newuserid = tk.StringVar()
    newpassid = tk.StringVar()
    SignUpWin = tk.Tk()
    NewUserLabel = tk.Label(SignUpWin, text="New Username: ").pack()
    NewUserInput = tk.Entry(SignUpWin,textvariable=newuserid).pack()
    NewPassLabel = tk.Label(SignUpWin, text="New Password: ").pack()
    NewPassInput = tk.Entry(SignUpWin, textvariable=newpassid).pack()

    CreateAccount = tk.Button(SignUpWin, text="Create Account", command=signupgo).pack()

def logingo():
    user = GetUser()
    password = GetPass()
    if user in accounts:
        if accounts[user] == password:
            LoggedIn(user)
        elif accounts[user] != password:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Wrong Password", 'Try Again! You have entered the wrong password.')
    elif user not in accounts:
        tkMessageBox.showerror("User not existing", 'Try Again or Create an account! The username you have provided is not existing.')

def LoggedIn(user):
    def MessageButtonClick():
        if tkMessageBox.askquestion('Compose or Inbox?', 'Do you want to access your inbox(Yes) or compose a new message(No)?') == 'yes':
            OpenInbox(user)
        else:
            MessageSender(user)
```

The message sending part starts here.

```
def MessageSender(user):
        messagerecvar = tk.StringVar()
        messagecontentvar = tk.StringVar()
        messagesenderwin = tk.Tk()
        messagereclabel = tk.Label(messagesenderwin, text="Receiver:").pack()
        messagerecinput = tk.Entry(messagesenderwin, textvariable=messagerecvar).pack()
        messagecontentlabel = tk.Label(messagesenderwin, text="Content:").pack()
        messagecontentinput = tk.Entry(messagesenderwin, textvariable=messagecontentvar).pack()
        messagecontent = messagecontentvar.get()
        messagerec = messagerecvar.get()
        messagesendgobutton = tk.Button(messagesenderwin, text='Send Message', command=lambda:sendmessagego(messagecontent, user, messagerec)).pack()
    def sendmessagego(content, sender, receiver):
        messages.append(content)
        messageno = len(messages)
        messagerec.append(receiver)
        messagesen.append(sender)
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message Sent", 'Your message has been sent.')
    def OpenInbox(user):
        if 'a' in messagerec:
            lenmess = messagerec.index(user)
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('Message from '+messagesen[lenmess], 'Message from '+messagesen[lenmess]+': '+messages[lenmess])
        elif user not in messagerec:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('No Messages', 'Sorry, no messages were found')
    loggedinwin = tk.Tk()
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome", 'Hello, '+user)
    HomeLabel = tk.Label(loggedinwin, text="Home").pack()
    MessageMenuButton = tk.Button(loggedinwin, text="Messaging", command=MessageButtonClick).pack()


maingui = tk.Tk()

userid = tk.StringVar()
passid = tk.StringVar()


UserEnterLabel = tk.Label(maingui, text="Username: ").pack()
UserInput = tk.Entry(maingui, textvariable=userid).pack()
PassEnterLabel = tk.Label(maingui, text="Password: ").pack()
PassInput = tk.Entry(maingui, textvariable=passid).pack()

LoginGo = tk.Button(maingui, text="Login", command=logingo).pack()

SignUpGo = tk.Button(maingui, text="Sign Up", command=SignUp).pack()


maingui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Users will be more willing and able to help if you show us a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that gets the error, including input, expected & actual output, and any warning or error messages (including compiler warnings). Take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and put yourself in the place of your readers. Have you included enough information? Is it clear what you're asking?

Comment: Sorry, I'll follow all that next time. I got so pissed off when it wasn't working that I forgot to do all that.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`. Tkinter isn't designed to work that way, and will yield unexpected results. If you need more than one window you need to create instances of `Toplevel`

Comment: I did that but still the same problem exists. Can you help me out in this?